# EF keep existing data during automatic migration

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am having a strange issue where my EF Automatic Migrations are removing all of the data within from **all** tables whenever I make a change to **any one** of the Entity's.

I've seen this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415921/entity-framework-code-first-migration-keep-existing-data?rq=1) however for the life of me I can't derive from the links what I am missing in my own implementation.

Note that the application works as completely fine, with data being retrieved and saved to the mysql database via EF - it's just a great annoyance to have to re-create all the data everytime I want modify an Entity.

I am using EF6.0 and a MySql database.

---

**Context.cs**

```
namespace Dock.Models
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class DockContext : DbContext
    {
        public DockContext(): base("name=DockContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DockInitializer());
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Dock> Docks { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Crate> Crates { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Confirguration.cs**

```
 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DockContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
            CodeGenerator = new MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
        }

        protected override void Seed(DockContext context)
        {
            Profile admin = new Profile {
                NotAPrimaryId = 168879070,
                DisplayName = "Admin101"
            };
            context.Profiles.AddOrUpdate(a => a.NotAPrimaryId , admin);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And an example of one of the Entity's **Dock.cs**

```
namespace Dock.Entities
{
    public class Dock
    {
        [Key]
        public int DockId { get; set; }
        public int ProfileId { get; set; }
        public int GameId { get; set; }
        public string GameData { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        // Navigational Properties
        [ForeignKey("CrateId")]
        public virtual List<Crate> Crates { get; set; } = new List<Crate>();
    }
}
```

Comment: My recommendation: Never use automatic migrations in an environment you care about. Whipping up a proof-of-concept? Sure. Team development, QA, or production environments? No.

Comment: @EricJ. So you would recommend just dropping the automatic migrations and start writing my own instead? The app is still in development (no real user data atm).. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: EF will create migration classes for you. You don't have to write them by hand. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621 Automatic migrations can cause problems in my experience when different team members commit updates at different times. I've also had to hand-edit the generated code-based migrations on several occasions, something that can't be done with automatic migrations

Comment: Thanks for the Insight @EricJ.

Comment: @EricJ. Changing to manual migrations has resolved this issue for me and I am very grateful. Did you want to post your comments as an answer? - They were helpful.

Comment: Sure, just posted it. Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF will [create migration classes for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621). You don't have to write them by hand.

Automatic migrations can cause problems in my experience when different team members commit updates at different times.

I've also had to hand-edit the generated code-based migrations on several occasions, something that can't be done with automatic migrations.

I suggest switching to manual migrations so that you have complete visibility into and control of the migration process.